# How to not leave button in selected state after click - fluent-ui (office ui fabric)

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

Using `DefaultButton` currently. This remains selected when clicked, which property can be used to revoke selection once clicked.

Alternatively, is there any styling that needs to be done for selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DefaultButton* `checked` property for that scenario and control it with *onClick* event:

```
const [isButtonChecked, setIsButtonChecked] = React.useState(false);

<DefaultButton
  checked={isButtonChecked}
  onClick={() => {
    setIsButtonChecked(!isButtonChecked);
  }}
  styles={{
    rootChecked: {
      backgroundColor: '#f00',
      color: '#fff',
    }
  }}
>
  Default Button
</DefaultButton>
```

Use `styles` property to modify button styles when button state is checked: *rootChecked, rootCheckedHovered etc.*

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/GRWdzVL)